Inconsistent build behavior
I have a pipeline for an onprem agent.  This is a .Net 8 web application.
I'm getting very inconsistent results.  Every once in a while I get a completed build.  Most of the time I'm getting a message like this:
2024-11-21T14:22:31.2057311Z   Restored E:\agent\_work\57\s\foo\source\ABC\TOPImportService\ABC.TOPImportService.csproj (in 192 ms).
2024-11-21T14:22:31.7260950Z   Restored E:\agent\_work\57\s\foo\source\ABC\src\ABC.Core\ABC.Core.csproj (in 737 ms).
2024-11-21T14:22:31.7261477Z   Restored E:\agent\_work\57\s\foo\source\ABC\src\XYZ.Notification\XYZ.Notification.csproj (in 496 ms).
2024-11-21T14:22:32.6002407Z   Restored E:\agent\_work\57\s\foo\source\ABC\src\ABC.PersistenceService\ABC.PersistenceService.csproj (in 856 ms).
2024-11-21T14:22:33.5381732Z   Restored E:\agent\_work\57\s\foo\source\ABC\src\ABC.Infrastructure\ABC.Infrastructure.csproj (in 2.53 sec).
2024-11-21T14:22:33.6414945Z   Restored E:\agent\_work\57\s\foo\source\ABC\TOPImportWorkerService\ABC.TOPImportWorkerService.csproj (in 2.63 sec).
2024-11-21T14:22:33.7495891Z   Restored E:\agent\_work\57\s\foo\source\ABC\src\ABC.Web\ABC.Web.csproj (in 2 sec).
2024-11-21T14:22:40.7093178Z C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.403\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4857,5): warning MSB3026: Could not copy "obj\Release\net8.0\XYZ.Notification.dll" to "bin\Release\net8.0\XYZ.Notification.dll". Beginning retry 1 in 1000ms. The process cannot access the file 'E:\agent\_work\57\s\foo\source\ABC\src\XYZ.Notification\obj\Release\net8.0\XYZ.Notification.dll' because it is being used by another process.  [E:\agent\_work\57\s\foo\source\ABC\src\XYZ.Notification\XYZ.Notification.csproj]

The 'file in use' often changes.  Sometimes it is multiple files.
Also - I'm not sure if it is trying to WRITE to the source folder (which wouldn't make sense to me).

Please clarify in details what "The 'file in use' often changes." you mean. Besides, please share the completed yaml file of your pipeline.

In the error above, the file in use is:
The process cannot access the file 'E:\agent_work\57\s\foo\source\ABC\src\XYZ.Notification\obj\Release\net8.0\XYZ.Notification.dll' because it is being used by another process.
In other runs (no code changes, same build agent) - the 'file in use' is a different file from the source code.

Please delete the obj and bin folders in your self-hosted agent folder E:\agent\_work\57\s\foo\source\ABC\src\XYZ.Notification, then rebuild the project and check if it works. To narrow down the issue, try to run the pipeline using a Microsoft-hosted agent, if it works, we can know the issue is related to the self-hosted agent or the local environment.

I changed publishWebProjects from 'false' to 'true' and the intermittent errors went away.
